# Importing a buck android project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, buck

I want to import an existing buck project into Eclipse. I do build the project successfully using
`buck build exampleApp`. Now when I import it as an Android project into Eclipse, I do not get any valid projects except some `res`, `bin`, and `gen` folders. 
I even tried creating a new Android project in Eclipse and copying `src` and `res` files manually. It is built successfully but the app does not run properly.

I was wondering if there is a way to appropriately import the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently.  Support for that is tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/65).